# How to fix [Found: 'android.content.Context', required: 'androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner' ] in BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-workmanager

This is not duplicate since my problem is `Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'android.content.Context', required: 'androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner'` and i didn't got any answer to fix this issue. I'm trying to implement work manager in backround service.

I've tried to Cast as AppCompatActivity, LifeCycleOwner , ... context it self won't work also...

Here's The code :

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
        .setRequiresCharging(true)
        .build();

final Data data = new Data.Builder()
        .putDouble(USER_LAT, maps.get(i).getUser_lat())
        .putDouble(USER_LNG, maps.get(i).getUser_lng())
        .putLong(MAP_ID, id)
        .putString(METHOD, maps.get(i).getMethod())
        .putString(STATUS, maps.get(i).getStatus())
        .putString(RECIEVED_DATA, maps.get(i).getCreate_time())
        .build();

final OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(DatabaseToApiWorker.class)
        .setInputData(data)
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .setInitialDelay(delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();

WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(oneTimeWorkRequest);
WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(oneTimeWorkRequest.getId())
        .observe((LifecycleOwner) context, new Observer<WorkInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(WorkInfo workInfo) {
                if (workInfo != null)
                    Log.e("ServiceWorker",workInfo.getState().name());
                if (workInfo.getState().isFinished())
                {
                    if (workInfo.getState() == WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED){

                        Data data1 = workInfo.getOutputData();
                        Long id = data1.getLong(DatabaseToApiWorker.MAP_ID_WORKER,0);
                        appDatabase.getMapDAO().deleteIt(id);
                        Log.e("ServiceWorker", String.valueOf(id));
                    } else if (workInfo.getState() == WorkInfo.State.FAILED) {

                        Log.e("ServiceWorker", String.valueOf(id)+" Sending Failed");
                    }

                } else {

                    Log.e("WORKER", String.valueOf(id)+" Failed");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Which version of the library are you using? do you have a sample project that reproduce the issue?

Comment: @pfmaggi Hello. I'm using 2.2.0 version of WorkManager.
what u mean by simple project? above code is working on my Activity, but it's not working on Receiver. if u mean is about sharing workmanager code, i just added. there's nothing more.

Comment: @pfmaggi also full error added. if u need anything more, thell me. i'm using this receiver for my location callback and it's working fine.

Comment: @pfmaggi nvm, i found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution i found my problem was implementing a custom lifecyclerOwner, here's the [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle).

Here's The code :
Add implementation :

```
public class MyLocationService extends BroadcastReceiver implements LifecycleOwner {
private LifecycleRegistry lifecycleRegistry;
```

In OnReceive ADD :

```
    lifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);
    lifecycleRegistry.markState(Lifecycle.State.CREATED);
```

Add this below to your class :

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
    return lifecycleRegistry;
}
```

then change context to `this::getLifecycle`